# При выводе (&not) в строке она заменяется на знак (¬)

Tags: php, unicode

У меня есть ассоциативный массив с помощью которого я создаю строку для GET запроса.

```
"el" => 1,
"id" => 2,
GET = "...el=1&id=2"
```

В моем массиве есть ключ **note** и когда я объединяю его с остальными элементами через знак **&** получается такая строка: "...el=1&id=2&note=41"

Проблема заключается в том, что при выводе часть (&not) в "...el=1&id=2 **&not**e=41" заменяется на знак (¬) - ...el=1&id=2**¬**e=41

Как можно это исправить?

Код:

```
$request_url = "...";

foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
         $used_value = htmlentities($value);
         $used_value = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $used_value);

         $request_url .= "{$key}={$used_value}&";
         }

echo $request_url;
```

Comment: [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php)... Если проблема остаётся - `http_build_query($array, '', '&amp;')`

Comment: @InDevX Спасибо, http_build_query($array, '', '&amp;') работает!